# How to make an icon link that functions the same as a submit button in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: html, laravel

I have custom function in my Model Controller called block, it sets a field in the database for one user from 0 to 1 or vice versa, in my index there's a datatable that displays users along with a `block/unblock button`, the datatable looks like this:

[image]

And now I remade my datatable to a better looking one using icons which looks like this

[image]

the problem is clicking on the block icon doesn't do anything this is the code for first blocking button:

```
<td>
    <form action="{{ route('users.block',$user->id) }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Bloquer</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

and this is the new code for the block icon

```
<td>
    <form action="{{ route('users.block',$user->id)}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <a class="icon" >
            <i class="fe fe-lock"></i>
        </a>
    </form>
</td>
```

I tried adding `type="submit"` to the icon properties but makes it look not the same and it doesn't work, I used `<button>` tag instead of `<i>` it works but it doesn't look like an icon, thanks for your patience

Comment: why don't you just pass url in href ?? like this `<a class="icon" href="{ route('users.block',$user->id)}}" >` you may need to change route to GET.

Comment: This worked thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're building a form, if you want it to work you need to submit it (that's what the HTML attribute `type="submit"` does). I don't think it will work if you put any other tag in here.

If your problem is only with the style of the button you could do this:

```
<td>
   <form action="{{ route('users.block',$user->id) }}" method="post">
                  @csrf
       <a class="icon" ><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><i class="fe fe-lock"></i></button></a>
   </form>
</td>
```

You can modify the CSS to make the button look as just a icon.

For more info click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

EDIT: Button without any style:

```css
.form-button {
 background: none;
 color: inherit;
 border: none;
 padding: 0;
 font: inherit;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: inherit;
}
```

```html
<button class="form-button">Put the other tags here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor tag for `submit` and add the icon code inside the `a` tag as below:

```
<td>
   <form action="{{ route('users.block', $user->id) }}" method="post">
           @csrf
       <a class="icon" type="submit"><i class="fe fe-lock"></i></a>
   </form>
</td>
```